# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Jobs_AspNetUsers_UserId' on table 'Jobs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities in my project, and I get an error when trying to update my database(SQL Server). I have looked around stack overflow, seen some people having the exact same problem as me, but when I try their fixes, I still get the same error. I have been tackling this error for a while now and I don't seem to know what exactly is wrong. Please I think I might need some help in figuring out this one.

My `AppUser` entity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> CreatedJobs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> AssignedJobs{ get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Watch> Watching { get; set; }
    public string Tagline { get; set; }
    public Socials Socials { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> SkillSet { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

My `Job` entity

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")] 
    public decimal InitialPrice { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string AssignedUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AssignedUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Watch> Watching { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public DeliveryTypes DeliveryType { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
}
```

What I've done for my table configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(c => c.CreatedJobs)
        .WithOne(t => t.User)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(c => c.AssignedJobs)
        .WithOne(t => t.AssignedUser)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.AssignedUserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

I have tried all the `DeleteBehavior` values and none seem to work.

I still get the error -

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (28ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> ALTER TABLE [Jobs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE
> CASCADE; Failed executing DbCommand (28ms) [Parameters=[],
> CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] ALTER TABLE [Jobs] ADD
> CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId])
> REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing
> FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Jobs_AspNetUsers_UserId' on table 'Jobs'
> may cause cycles or multiple ca scade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
> ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
> constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
> errors.

I know this question has been asked before. I have tried the fixes people suggested and it doesn't seem to work in my case, hence why I feel the need to ask again.

Comment: can u please share ur migration history for those Domain Models? 
i think its migration versioning issue. you added a migration then you added the cascade delete thingy, so its still breaking on the first one

Comment: oh.. ok, so should i delete previous migrations up to when i added the cascade?

Comment: first run Update-Database –TargetMigration: <name of last good migration>
then remove-migration name_of_bad_migration

now add a new migration 

if its help let me to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its migration versioning issue. you added a migration then you added the cascade delete thingy, so its still breaking on the first one ,to achieve that

run `Update-Database –TargetMigration: <name of last good migration>`

then

run `remove-migration name_of_bad_migration`

now add a new migration with the new change